# How to load jquery url in joomla (Component)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, joomla

How to load jquery url in joomla (Component) ?
I have one button. when click this button will reload page then i use get method for get value form variable to display.

JavaScript:

```
jQuery("#btnclickme").click(function(){
jQuery("#divpro").load("index.php?hello=hello");
});
```

PHP:

```
echo $_GET['hello'];
return;
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" id="btnclickme" name="btnclickme" />
<div id="divpro"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps you.

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_AJAX_to_your_component

Answer (score 0):

In index.php of your template in head section (after `<jdoc:include type="head" />`)

```
<?php
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("templates/yourtemplatename/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js");
```

And copy the jquery files to your templates directory.

Comment: how can i get url data from by using jquery .can give simple code ?

Comment: You can try this: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html